# Serialize class missing data

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

This is driving me mad right now, I am currently writing some client/server software, I can send arrays between clients without a problem but the problem lies in this code here:

```
MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
lock (fs)
        lock (sharedVars.clients[i])
            formatter.Serialize(fs, sharedVars.clients[i]);
    sender.SendData(setFirstByte(Game_Project_no._14wI542Z.Shared.Constants.InitialByte.REQUEST_RTN, fs.ToArray()));
```

I run the code and with breakpoints I can see that the memorystream contains data in it from the serialization however it never makes it to the other computer (this is actually all through localhost currently to avoid having actual network hardware errors).

This is using TCP and the real crazy part is that if I manually write a new byte array to the memorystream the data gets to the other side without a problem, essentially it just doesn't like the serialized data. It's really confusing me now so I pose the question to the community, any ideas?

For more reference this is what get called when the completely empty array (bar the request_rtn byte at the beginning) gets to the other end:

```
Shared.SharedValues.Client clientTemp;

readBuffer = removeFirstByte(readBuffer);

BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(readBuffer);

ms.Position = 0;

lock (serverValues)
    clientTemp = (Shared.SharedValues.Client)formatter.Deserialize(ms);

serverValues.clients[clientTemp.ID] = clientTemp;
```

And back on the server side the code I changed to test it, which works in every regard:

```
MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

byte[] byteArray = new byte[10000];

for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    byteArray[i] = (byte)i;
}

lock (fs)
    lock (sharedVars.clients[i])
        //formatter.Serialize(fs, sharedVars.clients[i]);
        fs.Write(byteArray, 0, 10000);
    sender.SendData(setFirstByte(Game_Project_no._14wI542Z.Shared.Constants.InitialByte.REQUEST_RTN, fs.ToArray()));
```

Comment: you checked the content of fs.toArray()?

Comment: In both cases they contain exactly what I expect.

Comment: Are both client and server using the same class definition for `Shared.SharedValues.Client`?

Comment: Yes they both have a shared library included which is a dll kept in another visual studio project.

Comment: How much data does your object serialize down to?  Is it possible that it just hasn't all arrived yet, and so fails to `Deserialize`?

Comment: The test code is over 6 times the size of the serialized byte array and that arrives instantly, equally if that were the case then I wouldn't get zeros on the other end.

Comment: Just checking if you have all the bases covered - is TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize set to a value higher than 8k? Are you handling partial content?

Comment: The recieveBufferSize is default, so 8.something k, however the plot thickens, after about 500 runs it worked for about 5 seconds and then the transfer going from the client to the server (in reverse) broke.

Comment: What does the `setFirstByte` method look like, and why is it necessary?

Comment: The set first byte method simply puts a byte at the front of the array, it is needed so I can identify what type of structure is going over the network as I send multiple different structures across. This first byte is removed before it is deserialized on the other side and it has been tested to cause no problems. I don't have the code to hand currently however it is essentially a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>After much toying around I ended up fixing the problem by simply writing the buffer to its self using:</strike>

```
fs.Write(fs.GetBuffer(), 0, fs.Capacity);
```

I feel there must be a compiler bug or something going on however this convinces it to behave. Now I shall move onto other problem which now arise.

Scrap that lot, turns out that the line above does nothing to help, the true error is that I was doing an asynchronous write and almost instantly the buffers that were being written to the network were being destroyed, this essentially means that 1 or 2 bytes get through and then a load of 0's. So for anyone that encounters this problem in future make sure you aren't doing something stupid like me.

Thank you for the enquirers that some of you have made in an attempt to work out what is going on.